# Searchbar with recyclerview and onQueryTextChange Listener

Tags: android, searchview

I created a searchview in android. And on using OnQueryTextChange () in OnQueryTextListener and adding getFilter() to adapter and running the app, the app opens correctly but on typing the text in search bar closes the app and shows a java.lang.NullpointException error near the onQueryTextChange().
Kindly help for my problem. Below is the code.

```
MainActivity
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
SearchView searchView;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   // Toolbar toolbar= new Toolbar(this);
   // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    searchView= (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.search);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycle);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    final MyAdapter myadapter= new MyAdapter(this,getStudents());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);

    if(searchView!=null) {


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                myadapter.getFilter().filter(query);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}

private ArrayList<Students> getStudents(){

    ArrayList<Students> students=new ArrayList<>();
    Students s= new Students();
    s.setImg(R.drawable.facebook);
    s.setName("Girish");
    s.setPosition("First");
    students.add(s);

    s=new Students();
    s.setImg(R.drawable.instagram);
    s.setName("Sirish");
    s.setPosition("second");
    students.add(s);

    s=new Students();
    s.setImg(R.drawable.twitter);
    s.setName("Harish");
    s.setPosition("Third");
    students.add(s);

    s=new Students();
    s.setImg(R.drawable.youtube);
    s.setName("Manish");
    s.setPosition("fourth");
    students.add(s);

    s=new Students();
    s.setImg(R.drawable.like);
    s.setName("Mahesh");
    s.setPosition("fifth");
    students.add(s);

    s=new Students();
    s.setImg(R.drawable.googleplus);
    s.setName("Raj");
    s.setPosition("Sixth");
    students.add(s);

    s=new Students();
    s.setImg(R.drawable.snapchat);
    s.setName("Ramesh");
    s.setPosition("Seventh");
    students.add(s);

    return students;
}
```

}

```
    MyAdapter:
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> implements Filterable{
Context c;
ArrayList<Students> students, filterlist;
CustomFilter filter;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Students> students) {
    this.c=context;
    this.students=students;
    this.filterlist=students;
}

@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model,null);

    MyHolder myHolder=new MyHolder(v);
    return myHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.positionTxt.setText(students.get(position).getPosition());
    holder.nameTxt.setText(students.get(position).getName());
    holder.img.setImageResource(students.get(position).getImg());

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "item created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return students.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(filter==null){
        filter= new CustomFilter(filterlist,this);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) adapter like `class MyAdapter extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<Student, MyAdapter.VH> {... `and override `matches()` method

Comment: unable to figure out with that link